# How do I get the x-coordinate into my plot?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe and I am wanting to generate a graph that has date in the x-axis and median value of price in the y-axis. How do I do that?

[image]

```
median_price.plot(x='Date', y='MedianPrice', kind='line')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using [`DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html). You could convert the index into a column:

```
median_price = median_price.reset_index()
median_price.plot(x='Date', y='MedianPrice', kind='line')
```

Comment: KeyError: 'Date'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-151-6b4fb049951b> in <module>
      2 median_price = avocado18.groupby('Date').median()
      3 
----> 4 median_price.plot(x='Date', y='MedianPrice', kind='line')
      5 
      6 #median_price.plot(kind='line', y='MedianPrice')

Comment: I noticed your price variable is labeled as 'MedianPrice' in the example code, whereas the the price variable is labeled as 'Price' in the graphic. Could you specify the real name of the variable in your dataframe? Also, I want to make sure you reset your index, because it looks like your 'Date' variable is set as the index, which may be causing the error if it is not converted from an index to a column.